# Twilio outbound voice call starts with delay

Tags: voip, twilio

I have just written my Twilio app to make an outbound voice call to my phone number in Indonesia.

When I answer the voice call, there is roughly 3-5 seconds of delay before the first audio plays, be it using `<Say>` or using `<Play>` verbs.

Do you guys know why this is the case and whether there is a current workaround to reduce this long delay to a mere 1-2 seconds? Recipients will most likely hang up the phone if there is no sound at all on the other end for too long.

Thanks in advance on any insight

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem - my outbound call to between 7 and 9 seconds to start playing the voicefile.

The process inside twilio ( from the delays measured when you look at each call with the http response time) accounted for about 3-4 seconds.

I also had AMD (Answering Machine Detection) on ie IfMachine=Continue.

(see documentation here 1. https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine 2. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection)

I removed this option from the call and the call start time reduced by 3 seconds down to about 5 seconds on average.

I think this is due to the AMD feature listening to the first few seconds of the call to determine if it was in fact answered by a human or a machine.

So, turn off AMD.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Off the top of my my first suggestion would be to make sure that the web app that Twilio is making the request to is returning a response quickly.  Twilio will wait for up to 15 seconds for your server to respond, so it might be that its just taking a bit for your server to respond.

If you test your URL and your server is returning a response quickly, then next suggestion is to send an email to help@twilio.com.  Our support team can dig into a phone call with you and see if there is a delay happening deeper thats causing Twilio to not get notified that the call has been answered, which would delay our HTTP request to your server.

Hope that helps.